# What is the correct term for an object or reference/pointer with an associated lock?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17

Something akin to, **Pseudocode:**

```
template<class T, class M>
struct X {
  std::unique_lock<M> associated_lock_;
  T* associated_obj_;
};
```

Use case:

```
{
  X x = getObj();//locking occurs
  //do something with x.associated_obj_
}//x gets unlocked due to scope exit
```

*I was thinking something in the lines of "Checkout" or "Access", if that would communicate the meaning. "Checkpoint" is probably bad. "ConcurrentY" or "ConcurrentObject", is usually an accepted naming for eg. a ConcurrentMap class, but that seems wrong in this context because that is not something where the locking mechanism itself is exposed like it is here.*

Comment: As an aside the idiom you're using often leads to very fragile code when devs forget to scope the value returned by `getObj` in the way shown.  Subsequent calls to `getObj` can then lead to various issues including UB (if the template parameter `M` is `std::mutex` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct term for an object or reference/pointer with an associated lock?

If the object is not accessible without locking methods (`private` with locking accessors), then we say that it is *thread-safe*.

If the wrapper acquires the resource at creation and takes care of the release at destruction (as `std::lock_guard` would do for example), we say that it is [*RAII*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (Resource acquisition is initialization).

But these terms apply to qualify the wrapper (`X` in your example), not the inner object (so I'm not sure if this answer is really what you are looking for).

---

**Edit:** By looking at your use-case it seems that the correct term here is RAII since the lock is bound to the lifetime of the object (which is exactly what RAII is).

Comment: I was thinking something in the lines of "Checkout" or "Access", if that would communicate the meaning. "Checkpoint" is probably bad. "ConcurrentY" or "ConcurrentObject", is usually an accepted naming for eg. a ConcurrentMap class, but that seems wrong in this context because that is not something where the locking mechanism itself isn't exposed like this.

Comment: @darune If all instances use the same mutex, I think what you are trying to build is a "timed singleton", only one instance can live at a time.